# Low utilization rate of CPUs for docker container

Tags: .net, docker, parallel-processing, containers, cpu

Although we are using multi threading (the parallelisation of execution intensive code parts) in our worker container on our 16 core server, only 4-6 CPUs are used. The code is written in C#/dotnet 2.2.

We don't set any max parameter to reduce the amount of CPUs on our linux server. And the execution intensive methods that are parallelized should use most of the CPUs.

Is there any recommendation how to check if there is any variable set wrongly, perhaps by default? Any hint of how to find out why the multi threading is not using more than those 4-6 cores? Any tool that is recommended to find out more details?

Thanks!

Checked the start script to start the docker container. docker stats shows only a percentage between 400-600%, what means that 4-6 CPU's are used.

Update:

It shouldn't be a technical problem as we could increase the workload of the CPU's to a maximum number with other test functions. When checking with the command "uptime" the average workload is mostly > 2.0. The fact is, our implementation uses multithreading and can scale up to 4-5 cores, but something, I guess the way of the implementation using parallel loops , are limiting the usage of CPUs. Any hint, what we could check too, before we have to change the whole implementation? We also checked that call:

```
int maxProcCount = Environment.ProcessorCount - 1;
```

It shows 5 with 6 cores (locally), so that can't be the problem.

Comment: How are you sure the docker-container is not being executed inside a virtualised ecosystem, where the "CPU-core-numbers" are virtualised ( creating internal illusion ), yet are subject to a resources sharing policy, governed by a HyperVisor, which stands beyond your visible horizon-of-virtualisation-abstraction and you cannot see, nor touch its policy-settings? From inside of the VM-ed execution of a docker-enclosed code-execution, one can but rely on available part of the "promised" resources. Those unavailable are simply not working for your VM-abstracted eco-system ( even if advertised so )

Comment: The server is offered by a company's it administritation and we don't have any possibilities to take a look in such sharing policy. Is there any command or tool that could give an hint, where we have to look in detail?